# Detect Dropbox Authorization in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, air, dropbox

I have an Adobe AIR application that connects to Dropbox. When the users connects their Dropbox account for the first time, I use an HTMLLoader to display the authorization page.

I need to be able to detect when the user has successfully linked their Dropbox account with my application.. this page will display:

[image: Successful Dropbox app link screen]

I'm using [dropbox-as3](https://code.google.com/p/dropbox-as3/) to connect to Dropbox. Right now, I'm listening for the user to close the window, but I was wondering if there was any way I can skip this step.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: I'm not familiar with the dropbox-as3 library, so I don't know if this is implemented in it, but it looks like it uses OAuth 1, so the normal way to handle this is using the oauth_callback parameter on the /authorize page: https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/docs#authorize That would redirect the user to some page specified by the app. The app would normally then detect that and resume functionality from there.

Answer (score 0):

I never tried to use this library or Integrate DropBox with AS3, but, maybe they have some event, that is triggered when the account is linked? So, you could listen to this event instead of the windows/close.

I found this one: [ACCOUNT_INFO_RESULT](http://dropbox-as3.googlecode.com/svn/docs/dropbox-doc/index.html) on the official documentation, that may could help.

Comment: accountInfo() requires an access token, which is only received _after_ the user has linked their account. Am I stuck with listening for the window to close?